# Edited file after calling `sudo visudo`

Tags: terminal, sudo, macintosh, editors

To view permissions, I called `sudo visudo` in terminal.

When I wanted to exit from the editor, I pressed `control-x` (on the Mac, it exits `nano` editor, but it was apparently not `nano`). Instead, it deleted a character. I didn't notice, and I pressed it a few times before I realized I was deleting characters from the file.

I quit and reopened terminal, and called `sudo visudo` again.
I got this (I redacted the name of my computer):
[image]

I want to revert to whatever the file was before this fiasco. What do I do to revert to the old file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a temporary file that was in all likelihood not saved to the actual `/etc/sudoers` file on account of you quitting the terminal; `visudo` only makes changes to `/etc/sudoers` should the editor (here, `vim`) exit without errors. So there's nothing to revert to, as nothing was changed.

As for the temporary swap file, `D` to delete it should suffice, as that's only a throwaway temporary file from your previous efforts.